# Python Scatter Plot - with smooth Line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe as below (obtained after lot of preprocessing)

Please find dataframe

```
d = {'token': {361: '180816_031', 119: '180816_031', 101: '180816_031', 135: '180816_031', 292: '180816_031',
           133: '180816_031', 99: '180816_031', 270: '180816_031', 19: '180816_031', 382: '180816_031',
           414: '180816_031', 267: '180816_031', 218: '180816_031', 398: '180816_031', 287: '180816_031',
           155: '180816_031', 392: '180816_031', 265: '180816_031', 239: '180816_031', 237: '180816_031'},
 'station': {361: 'deneb', 119: 'callisto', 101: 'callisto', 135: 'callisto', 292: 'callisto', 133: 'deneb',
             99: 'callisto', 270: 'callisto', 19: 'deneb', 382: 'callisto', 414: 'deneb', 267: 'callisto',
             218: 'deneb', 398: 'callisto', 287: 'deneb', 155: 'deneb', 392: 'deneb', 265: 'callisto',
             239: 'callisto', 237: 'callisto'},
 'cycle_number': {361: 'cycle09', 119: 'cycle06', 101: 'cycle04', 135: 'cycle01', 292: 'cycle04', 133: 'cycle05',
                  99: 'cycle06', 270: 'cycle07', 19: 'cycle04', 382: 'cycle08', 414: 'cycle04', 267: 'cycle10',
                  218: 'cycle07', 398: 'cycle08', 287: 'cycle09', 155: 'cycle08', 392: 'cycle06', 265: 'cycle02',
                  239: 'cycle09', 237: 'cycle07'},
 'variable': {361: 'adj_high_quality_reads', 119: 'short_pass', 101: 'short_pass', 135: 'cell_mask_bilayers_sum',
              292: 'adj_active_polymerase', 133: 'cell_mask_bilayers_sum', 99: 'short_pass',
              270: 'adj_active_polymerase', 19: 'Unnamed: 0', 382: 'adj_high_quality_reads',
              414: 'num_align_high_quality_reads', 267: 'adj_active_polymerase', 218: 'adj_single_pores',
              398: 'num_align_high_quality_reads', 287: 'adj_active_polymerase', 155: 'cell_mask_bilayers_sum',
              392: 'num_align_high_quality_reads', 265: 'adj_active_polymerase', 239: 'adj_single_pores',
              237: 'adj_single_pores'},
 'value': {361: 99704.0, 119: 2072785.0, 101: 2061059.0, 135: 1682208.0, 292: 675306.0, 133: 1714292.0,
           99: 2072785.0, 270: 687988.0, 19: 19.0, 382: np.nan, 414: 285176.0, 267: 86914.0, 218: 948971.0,
           398: 405196.0, 287: 137926.0, 155: 1830032.0, 392: 480081.0, 265: 951689.0, 239: 681452.0,
           237: 882671.0}}
```

**Data:**

```
          token   station cycle_number                      variable  \
19   180816_031     deneb      cycle04                    Unnamed: 0   
99   180816_031  callisto      cycle06                    short_pass   
101  180816_031  callisto      cycle04                    short_pass   
119  180816_031  callisto      cycle06                    short_pass   
133  180816_031     deneb      cycle05        cell_mask_bilayers_sum   
135  180816_031  callisto      cycle01        cell_mask_bilayers_sum   
155  180816_031     deneb      cycle08        cell_mask_bilayers_sum   
218  180816_031     deneb      cycle07              adj_single_pores   
237  180816_031  callisto      cycle07              adj_single_pores   
239  180816_031  callisto      cycle09              adj_single_pores   
265  180816_031  callisto      cycle02         adj_active_polymerase   
267  180816_031  callisto      cycle10         adj_active_polymerase   
270  180816_031  callisto      cycle07         adj_active_polymerase   
287  180816_031     deneb      cycle09         adj_active_polymerase   
292  180816_031  callisto      cycle04         adj_active_polymerase   
361  180816_031     deneb      cycle09        adj_high_quality_reads   
382  180816_031  callisto      cycle08        adj_high_quality_reads   
392  180816_031     deneb      cycle06  num_align_high_quality_reads   
398  180816_031  callisto      cycle08  num_align_high_quality_reads   
414  180816_031     deneb      cycle04  num_align_high_quality_reads   

         value  
19        19.0  
99   2072785.0  
101  2061059.0  
119  2072785.0  
133  1714292.0  
135  1682208.0  
155  1830032.0  
218   948971.0  
237   882671.0  
239   681452.0  
265   951689.0  
267    86914.0  
270   687988.0  
287   137926.0  
292   675306.0  
361    99704.0  
382        NaN  
392   480081.0  
398   405196.0  
414   285176.0
```

I am trying to create scatterplot with smooth line

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(16,4)

#to get different colors for each of the `variable` value assign the variable to hue
g2=sns.lmplot(x='cycle_number',y='value',data=df, hue='variable',  size=4, aspect=5)
```

This code gives plots only one value for scatter plot, however my expected output is as below

**Expected Output:**

[image]

TRIES RESULT

TRY 1

I tried to create bar plot (with some help) & i was successful but with scatter plot I could not do it

Below code to convert same to bar

```
df1 = df.groupby(['token','variable']).agg({'value': 'mean'})
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1.sort_values('value',inplace=True,ascending=False)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(16,8)
#to get different colors for each of the variable assign the variable to hue
g=sns.barplot(x='token',y='value',data=df1, hue='variable',ax=ax)
#Code for to put legend outside the plot
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
# Put a legend to the right of the current axis
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
# Adding respective values to the top of each bar
for p in ax.patches: 
    ax.annotate("%d" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()),
                ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='black', xytext=(0, 10), 
                textcoords='offset points',fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

TRY 2

```
g2=sns.lmplot(x='cycle_number',y='value',data=df), this gives error 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'cycle10'
```

I know what the error means here but I am feeling helpless trying to replicate to output code

TRY 3:

```
sns.lmplot('cycle_number', 'value', data=df, hue='variable', fit_reg=False)
```

OUTPUT GENERATED: Blank GRID

Comment: your dataframe is incomplete missing ending brackets.

Comment: @Nihal, Thank you Nihal I have updated the dataframe

Comment: can post the image of what are you getting?

Comment: @Nihal, updated my tries with results generate. I think last try is what I would be looking for but I am missing something in that. Please help

Comment: working on that

Answer (score 6):

use:

```
sns.pointplot('cycle_number', 'value', data=df, hue='variable')
```

[image]

**documnetation:**  https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html

OUTPUT GENERATE USING THIS VS EXPECTED OUTPUT

[image]

[Expected OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDQYI.jpg)

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['cycle_number'] = df['cycle_number'].str.replace('cycle', '')
df['cycle_number'] = df['cycle_number'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
print(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(16, 4)
# sns.pointplot('cycle_number', 'value', data=df, hue='variable', err_style="bars", ci=68)
sns.lmplot('cycle_number', 'value', data=df, hue='variable', ci=None, order=2, truncate=True)
# use order = 5 to see more curve
```

**output for `order=2`**

[image]

*OUTPUT as per the latest code shared ( for `order=2`)*

[image: Final Output] - The legend is overlapping with graph area

OUTPUT 4  ( for `order=5`)*:
[image: USING ORDER =5]

The graph curve is perfectly fine except that the legend overlaps with plotting area.

Comment: Thanks Nihal, however the ouput requires me to have a curved smooth line across my points, The code mentioned above just connects all the points

Comment: I have added generated output Vs Expected Output above, for your reference. Please check the difference

Comment: i know the problem with lmplot. It requires cycles to be float value which happans to be string in your case. that's y it data give error with lmplot

Comment: Nihal, Please Note I have put output of code which was shared by you above, It is different from expected output in the sense that it is not smooth line but a line connecting the points. Please help in that

Comment: I know that. i tried with lmplot but it will only give linear output, not curved. you should look into fast fourier transform. which is used for cured graph output

Comment: No Problem, Can you please tag any experienced Mentor who would be familiar with this type of problem. Please

Comment: NIhal, Please find output of Code, It works perfectly except the overlapping part, Please help sort that out & it will be perfect !

Comment: argument order is the key to go. of order is >1 then it will give curverd grahp

Comment: Agree! Can you please see the overlapping grid problem & suggest why that is happening

Comment: this can be done better if you use `np.polyfit` in your data then use lmplot

Comment: I am sorry, I am relatively new to this (Extreme apologies) but I  mean to say that legend is overlapping in the grid area, can you share resolution to that from the code that we are running.

Comment: as i told increase the order to get more curve

Comment: use order = 5, and check

Comment: may be tomorrow or you can ask new question for that

Comment: i suggest you should ask saperate question for that matter. because your question is related to get curved output which i have already answered. if you do that you will get better response. may get reputation as well.

Comment: Did not know about that, Accepted the answer with biggest of thanks ! Can you please look at this query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013973/issue-in-error-bars-in-seaborn-barplot-python
I just need help with err plot